# Prerequisites to Learning Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, education

I am a freshman, rising sophomore that is interested in learning Real Analysis, since it is required for many higher mathematics subjects.  I have currently Calculus I, II, and Linear Algebra.  Is self-study in Real Analysis possible now, or should I wait until after taking Multivariate Calculus?

Comment: It's possible now.

Comment: Thank you.  Any suggestions on books, MOOCs, or videos?  I'm looking at Saylor Academy online right now.

Comment: Check out [OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100b-analysis-i-fall-2010/). This is the first course in real analysis at MIT.

Comment: Also, "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" is a classic when it comes to real analysis. I can't really compare it to other texts, though.

Comment: There are many books on Real Analysis. For example, K.G. Binmore's Mathematical Analysis, a straightforward approach, Maxwell Rosenlicht's Introduction to Analysis, Richard Johnsonbaugh and W.E. Pfaffenberger's Foundations of Mathematical Analysis... More thorough are Apostol's books and Rudin's books. There is also Tao's books.

Comment: @Mark Thank you.  I'll look into it!

Comment: I think Tao talks about the construction of the number systems, but frequently this is omitted in mathematical analysis books. There is Landau's book "Grundlagen der Analysis" that is devoted to this. Surely there are graduate texts in mathematics that do this too.

Comment: For a first book, I'd go with Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*.  Then afterward maybe Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (through chapter 8 -- there are better books for the multivariable parts).